# Multiple SSIS Package Trouble

Tags: ssis

i have n number of customer , who share their data in a text file. i need to load data and do some checks.

i am trying to create a **SSIS** Package which will execute whenever a file drop to folder.

may any one suggest how to achieve it.

my plan:-

create n number of folder and n number of tables and n number of SSIS Package for respective customer, and load data to a table.

two concern:

will n number of table is good idea?

**how to design a package so whenever file drop package start executing it.**

Kindly share your valuable thoughts.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modeling

Will N tables be a good approach. Maybe? What are you trying to do with your data? If you are importing marketing contact data for Bridgestone, Toyo and Michelin tires, then you'd likely want to keep that data separated in physically different tables lest you accidentally give a company access to competitor data.

However, if you're pulling all that same data in because you're running a tire safety website, then you likely *do* want to store all the customer data in a single table.

### Package execution

There are two approaches - an event driven model (file added and process begins)  and a polling model (every N time units check to see if a file exists). I've used both in my life and can safely say that while both approaches have had issues where they've "missed" a file, the polling model is the *only* one that will correct itself without manual intervention. Sure, you only have to redrop the file in the event driven/file watcher approach but you generally only ever know the process didn't work when the client calls and is asking why the data isn't loaded. Then you look foolish at best.

Comment: Thanks , Please help me on how to design Polling model.